# Windows Phone - cancel back from mainpaga.xaml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to override the backbutton on mainpage. What works on other pages does not work on main. Here's my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        if (MessageBox.Show("Wszystkie zmiany zostaną odrzucone", "Odrzucenie Zmian", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it shows the messagebox to confirm exit, however it is also exiting the application, so confirming or cancelling makes no sense anyway.

Comment: Why is your question tagged [wpf] if it is about Windows Phone?

Comment: Suggestions. Corrected. Besides - i don't think it's mutually exclusive.

Comment: Is it MainPage? If so there is nothing to go back.

Comment: Yes - it is a mainpage - and I want to override the default back button behavior which in this case is "quit the bloody thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override OnBackKeyPress instead of  OnNavigatingFrom

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Wszystkie zmiany zostaną odrzucone", "Odrzucenie Zmian", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
            e.Cancel = true; 

    }
}
```